# Generalized Suffix Tree Java Implementation

Tags: java, suffix-tree

I am looking for a Java implementation of the Generalized Suffix Tree (GST) with the following features:

After the creation of the GST from say 1000 strings I would like find out how many of these 1000 strings contains some other string 's'.

The search must be quiet fast, as I need to apply the search on about 100'000 candidate strings of average length 10.

Comment: Hi, i Was wondering is you could tell me which soulution did you use in the end, i have the same issue!!!

Comment: look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english/9513423#9513423

Answer (score 4):

Try [The Semantic Discovery Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/semanticdiscoverytoolkit/). It has an implementation on text/src/java/org/sd/text/radixtree

Comment: Er, do you know of any implementations (or even tutorials!) for Token Suffix Trees?

Answer (score 4):

I created a suffix tree in Java that allows you easily add your own search functionality and other matching algorithms. My blog post, [Suffix Trees in Java](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2011/12/15/suffix-trees-java.xhtml), has an overview as well as instructions for downloaded the latest version. My Java implementation is based on Mark Nelson's [Fast String Searching With Suffix Trees](https://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/) article.

**Update 2023-04-01**

- The library containing the suffix tree implementation described above is now available on GitHub in the [globalmentor-base](https://github.com/globalmentor/globalmentor-base) repository in the [globalmentor-core](https://github.com/globalmentor/globalmentor-base/tree/main/core) subproject in the [`com.globalmentor.collections`](https://github.com/globalmentor/globalmentor-base/tree/main/core/src/main/java/com/globalmentor/collections) package.
- The latest version of the library is available from Maven Central using the artifact coordinates [`com.globalmentor:globalmentor-core`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.globalmentor%20AND%20a:globalmentor-core) .

Comment: The blog post is informative but the source is not currently available (Aug'2015) as it points to  https://svn.globalmentor.com/java/trunk/globalmentor-core/ which password protected.

Comment: I'm doing my best to convert our repository from Subversion to Git and make it public again. That should happen within a week or two. Feel free to ping me if it's not available by then. Cheers.

Comment: The source code is now available via Git and on Maven Central. I've updated the answer above with the new location.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @trincot. I've updated the links here and in the blog entry as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Java implementation of a Non-General Suffix Tree is available at: http://illya-keeplearning.blogspot.com/2009/04/suffix-trees-java-ukkonens-algorithm.html

Comment: If it's a direct port of Mark Nelson's, then it isn't a generalized suffix tree. It's just a suffix tree.

Comment: Right, I reworded my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an implementation of a [Generalized Suffix Tree in Java](https://github.com/abahgat/suffixtree) here.
I tried to document it as much as I could, so you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of SuffixTree:
https://github.com/losvald/sglj/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sglj/util/PATTrie.java

Among other things, it supports storing arbitrary data in nodes, and finding the set of values associated with the prefix.