# I want to find the strings that repeated more than 1 times

Tags: string, arraylist

I have an array of strings.

Some of The strings are similar (for example, **person** is similar to **twolegperson**, *animal* is similar to *animalgold*).

I want to find the strings that are repeated more than 1 times (here **person**,*animal*).

Thank you very much 
faty

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: and how are the strings stored?

Comment: i use java.  The strings stored in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Generalized Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_suffix_tree). For implementations see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969448/generalized-suffix-tree-java-implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Naive pseudocode alogrithm:

```
int minMatchLen = 3;   // The minimum length of string match required
string stringArray[] = {"person", "twolegperson", "animal", "animalgold"}
for (i = 0; i < stringArray.length, i++) {
    int strLen = stringArray[i].length;
    for (substrIndex = 0; substrIndex < strLen - minMatchLen; substrIndex++) {
        for (substrLen = minMatchLen; substrLen < strLen - substrIndex; substrLen++) {
            string subString = stringArray[i].substr(substrIndex, substrLen);
            bool matchFound = false;
            for (j = i + 1; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                if stringArray[j].contains(subString) {
                    print("String '" + subString + "' found in '" + stringArray[j] + "'");
                    matchFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (matchFound) print(""String '" + subString + "' found in '" + stringArray[i] + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

This basically goes through each string in the array, extracts all possible substrings over a specified minimum length, and then search the strings in the remainder of the array for those substrings.  I'm sure there are more elegant and efficient solutions, but this will get the job done.  It'll probably be slow for a large array, though.